# The application does not work after publishing in the Google market. R8

Tags: java, android, proguard, google-developers-console, android-r8

I can’t understand why the code stopped working correctly after being published in the Google market in the release branch.

**Step 1.** Problem of the following character: 1. Turn on "minifyEnabled true", configure the proguard-rules.pro file. I write there the names of classes whose code does not need to be changed (-keep public class myClassName ...)

I check all this on the local computer - everything works (As you can see, the same settings for both release and debug)

I upload to the Google market - a branch of internal testing. Does not work.

**Step 2.** Turn off "minifyEnabled false".

I upload the code to the Google market in the internal testing branch. Surprisingly, everything works.

Ok, I'm trying to copy the current version from the internal branch to the release branch.

And, after the publication, this version of the application does not work again.

First, I have "minifyEnabled" turned off, but the app behaves like it's enabled. The application also starts to crumble in other places because of the encrypted variables, nonsense is passed to my functions and because of this they break.

Although I also have a "proguard-rules.pro" file with the rules configured correctly.

**Step 3.** I repeated step 2, only uploaded directly to the release branch, everything is exactly the same. Doesn't want to work.

Files:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// Apply the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 40
        versionName "1.0"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", applicationId + "-v" + versionCode + "(" + versionName + ")")
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/DEPENDENCIES', 'META-INF/LICENSE', 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt', 'META-INF/license.txt', 'META-INF/NOTICE', 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt', 'META-INF/notice.txt', 'META-INF/ASL2.0']
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.my.app'
}

dependencies {
    //firebase auth
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'

    // google
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0'
    //firebase-crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    //google billing
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:5.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1"
    //default
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
    implementation 'com.nex3z:flow-layout:1.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    //JUnit 4 Test
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1"

}
```

next file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        classpath 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keep public class myClassName
```

Comment: If you are seeing issues with using `minifyEnabled true` please take a look at [Shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) to get some more background on how R8 works. Also I am surprised that the line `-keep public class myClassName` in your `proguard-rules.pro` does not fail, as it is not valid syntax. See [ProGuard manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage) for the syntax.

Comment: Issue resolved. I brought all third-party libraries into the proguard-rules.pro

Comment: What do you mean by "I brought all third-party libraries into the proguard-rules.pro"? If you added a `-keep class <packagename>.**` for all library packages you are mostly turning off R8. You might want to narrow this down to a smaller set of libraries and work with the library provides on finding the most precise keep rules. You can open an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788 with your findings so we can give some advise.